# Two tables in a single module MAGENTO 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers

I have two tables for my module. First table are: Main table:

value_id | website_id | name

Second table are a relationship of two tables:

value_id | entity_id

My Controller.php:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$ramoModel2 = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associacao');
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0) {
    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
} else {
    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar');
}

$entitys = $postData['entity_id'];
$ramoModel->setCreatedTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());
$ramoModel->setId_erp($postData['id_erp'])
    ->setName($postData['name'])
    ->setWebsite_id($postData['website_id'])
    ->setId()
    ->save();
$ramoModel2->setId(1)
    ->setEntity_id(1)
    ->save();
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

I can not make it work, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have a Resource Model

   ```
   Integravet_Associar_Model_Resource_Associacao 
     extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
           protected function _construct() {
               $this->_init('integravet_associar/tableName', 'primary_id' );
           }
   }
   ```
2. And your Model Constructor points to Resource Model

   ```
   class Integravet_Associar_Model_Associacao 
     extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
   {
          protected function _construct() {
                parent::_construct();
                //Resource Name 
                $this->_init('integravet_associar/associacao ');
          }
   }
   ```

To do a simple save you don't need _before/_afterSave. With your resource model connected you should be able to put in data.

Comment: Cool if it works go ahead and accept the answer so other folks know and I get these points :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code: You didnt mention anything about `id_erp` and `created_time` in your question.

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$ramoModel2 = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associacao');
if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0) {
    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
} else {
    $ramoModel = Mage::getModel('integravet_associar/associar');
}

$entitys = $postData['entity_id'];
$ramoModel->setCreatedTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
    ->setIdErp($postData['id_erp'])
    ->setName($postData['name'])
    ->setWebsiteId($postData['website_id'])
    ->setId()
    ->save();
$ramoModel2->setValueId(1)
    ->setEntityId(1)
    ->save();
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

Comment: id_erp and created_time not important to relationship. thats why i didn't mentio.

Comment: Not work... I have read about aftersave and beforesave, and i dont know how to do that in my module...

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get a error, but still not saving in table2...

Comment: Is it saving in Table 1??

Comment: In table1 yes, but in table2 not.

Comment: Please make sure that your model is loading correctly and database fields are same

Comment: I do it, i verified my models, rewrite hims, but not insert in table2 yet.